# Backbone nested views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I'm working on a Backbone application and I'm not sure if the way what I'm trying to do is the correct way.

I have an application view and inside that application view I'm trying to append a collection view, and each view in that collection is a collection too.

Let me explain that graphically.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                    |
|    Application view                                                |
|                                                                    |
|    -------------------------------------------------------------   |
|    |  Windows Collection view                                  |   |
|    |                                                           |   |
|    |  --------------------------   --------------------------  |   |
|    |  | Tabs collection view   |   | Tabs collection view   |  |   |
|    |  |                        |   |                        |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |   | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  |                        |   |                        |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |   | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  |------------------------|   |------------------------|  |   |
|    |                                                           |   |
|    |  --------------------------   --------------------------  |   |
|    |  | Tabs collection view   |   | Tabs collection view   |  |   |
|    |  |                        |   |                        |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |   | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  |                        |   |                        |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |   | |Tab view| |Tab view|  |  |   |
|    |  | ---------- ----------  |   | ---------- ----------  |  |   |
|    |  |------------------------|   |------------------------|  |   |
|    |                                                           |   |
|    -------------------------------------------------------------   |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I'm loading the application view from the `initialize` method in my Backbone router. That view loads the `Windows collection view`.

The main problem is that I'm not sure if I'm on the right way. 
The second problem is that I'm not really sure how to load each `Tabs collection view` from my `Windows Collecion view`.

PS: Just to make things even clearer, I'm trying to replicate Firefox's panorama view: http://i.i.com.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim//2010/08/24/firefox-panorama.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just posting this here so others can see how I solved the problem

A working demo of the solution can be [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/NH9J6/155/) ([original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NH9J6/146/)).

As you can see from the link, the work is done thanks to Marionette's CompositeView which lets recursively render collections.

```
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        if(this.model.tabs){
            this.template = "#window-template";
        }else{
            this.template = "#tab-template";
        }
        this.collection = this.model.tabs;
    },

    appendHtml: function(cv, iv){
        cv.$("#tabs").append(iv.el);
    },
    onRender: function() {
        if(_.isUndefined(this.collection)){
            this.$("#tabs").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

The small trick I'm using in the initialize (the if/else with the template asignation) works the following way:

I get the current model and check if it has a "tabs" key. If it does have it, it means that the current model is a Window Data Model, so I need to use the `window-template`, else use the `tab-template`

The rest is pretty much plain Backbone structure.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using [Marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) to structure your application.

It already has collection views built in which makes rendering easy. Your application seems to be a perfect use case. You will get a lot of boilerplate code for free.