# Backbone.js and nested collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is a detailed question (with some of mmy code) of this other one: [Backbone nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637493/backbone-nested-views)

The other question contains a graphical representation of what I'm trying to achieve, but I think that if I write some code that'll help my question get resolved.

I have a big array or data of the following structure:

```
[
    {
        window: { <window-relative data>},
        tabs: [
            { <tab-relative data>},
            { <tab-relative data>}
        ]
    },

    {
        window: { <window-relative data>},
        tabs: [
            { <tab-relative data>},
            { <tab-relative data>}
        ]
    }
]
```

I can't query just the tabs of a window, nor just a single window. The data is as-is and there is no possibility at splitting it in any way. Let's just leave it at that the data is bootstrapped (and the way that it's bootstrapped can't be changed).

Keeping on with the question: I have a WindowsCollection:

```
myapp.WindowCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : WindowModel,

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('reset', this.onReset);
    },

    onReset: function(){
        // ...
    }

});
```

And a tabs collection which looks pretty much the same. I also have a Window model and a Tab model.

When the page loads completely, the following code is ran to load the data into the window collection: `myapp.myWindowCollection.reset(<data here>);`

My question is: where and how should I initialize the tab collections? In the ```onReset``? 
Let's assume I do something like

```
onReset: function(){
    _.each(this.models, function(window_data){
        t = new TabsCollection();
        t.reset(window_data.tabs);
    });
}
```

Then my nested collections (the Tabs collections) will have the right data, but then how could I create the view of each Tabs collection?

I could do:

```
onReset: function(){
    _.each(this.models, function(window_data){
        t = new TabsCollection();
        t.reset(window_data.tabs);
        tv = new TabsCollectionView(
            collection: t;
        );
    });
}
```

but then I would be messing views and collections and I'm feeling this is really messy.
Is there some better way that doesn't involve messing with views and collections in the same place?

Comment: I think you really can get a lot of benefits adding Marionette to your project, one of the nice things of marionette is that you can add only the parts you need, in this case I think collectionView and ItemView will definitly help you.

Comment: @Rayweb_on I should try Marionette. Do you know where could I get an example (or something similar) to what I'm asking for?

Comment: a collectionview knows how to render its itemViews so once you pass the collection of models to the collectionview it will render them for you with out you doing much code. Please review the documentation on github for marionette, and then try this tutorial.http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/

Comment: @Rayweb_on the problem is that I'm trying to have a few collections inside a collection. (The same as, each WindowView is a collection of tabs, and my whole ApplicationView is a collection of WindowViews)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting this here so others can see how I solved the problem

A working demo of the solution can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/NH9J6/146/

As you can see from the link, the work is done thanks to Marionette's CompositeView which lets recursively render collections.

```
var TreeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        if(this.model.tabs){
            this.template = "#window-template";
        }else{
            this.template = "#tab-template";
        }
        this.collection = this.model.tabs;
    },

    appendHtml: function(cv, iv){
        cv.$("#tabs").append(iv.el);
    },
    onRender: function() {
        if(_.isUndefined(this.collection)){
            this.$("#tabs").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

The small trick I'm using in the initialize (the if/else with the template asignation) works the following way:

I get the current model and check if it has a "tabs" key. If it does have it, it means that the current model is a Window Data Model, so I need to use the `window-template`, else use the `tab-template`

The rest is pretty much plain Backbone structure.